# xsl put all children of an element in a comment block

Tags: xml, xslt

I am transforming some xml that has mathml embedded in it. The target xml file we will be going to, does not support mathml. I would like to output that mathml within a comment block, so that the mathml would not get lost, but would also not cause a validation error wrt to the target dtd.

i had tried a:

```
    <xsl:comment><xsl:copy-of select="*"/></xsl:comment>
```

But that doesn't quite do it.

any help is greatly appreciated!

thanks,

Russ

Comment: btw, the full template is: 

 <xsl:template match="inlineequation">
  <InlineEquation>
  <xsl:comment>Equation goes here!</xsl:comment>
  <xsl:comment><xsl:copy-of select="*"/></xsl:comment>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
   <ImageObject>
   </ImageObject>
  </InlineEquation>
 </xsl:template>

Comment: Using XML comments to preserve content is a bad idea. Many parsers and tools will totally disregard comments.

Comment: I know. I was just trying to keep that info for your graphics people, because they CAN use it to create the equations as an external graphic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [XSLT spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Creating-Comments) says:

> It is an error if instantiating the content of `xsl:comment` creates nodes other than text nodes.

A possible work-around is to create the comments using `disable-output-escaping`:

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!--</xsl:text>
<xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">--&gt;</xsl:text>
```

Comment: Since he helped you, why not accept his answer?  Also consider reviewing some of your past 14 questions and accepting any other helpful answers you've received; there's got to be at least a few acceptable answers in there.  Here's how to accept an answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/234215

Comment: By the way, that quote is from the XSLT 1.0 spec. In XSLT 2.0, xsl:comment works like xsl:value-of - if there are element nodes in the content, their string value is used.

Comment: Be aware of the drawbacks of using d-o-e. It basically works only if the output of the transformation is being piped directly into a serializer, which means your transformation is no longer reusable and composable.